# Modifing Eclipse Outline view for CSS files

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, outline-view

How can I cause Eclipse's Outline view to do any of the following when displaying the outline for a CSS file:

1. display a comment
2. create a collapsible range for a group of CSS rules
3. anything else?

Thanks

CLARIFICATION:
I am not talking about doing code modifications to eclipse.
I was wandering if there is already some hidden way to do the said stuff.
(like adding a css comment that starts with the word OUTLINE or something similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found myself a workaround :)

Its not perfect but still...

Adding a CSS rule like this:

`._________________________ CONTROLS _________________________ {}`

shows up in the outline view very nicely.

I guess, if I don't put in too many of them, the runtime effect would be minimal.